# how to send one single status mail having status of multiple pipelines, without using logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I want to send a single status email having all pipelines status, without using logic apps.
Is it possible to share it from dashboard or kusto query output?

I set the alert but it is sending 2 mails(activate, deactivate) for each pipeline status individually. In that case so many status mails are coming.

Comment: what's the pipeline?

Comment: Azure data factory pipelines status I want to send in an email..

Comment: Not sure I understood you. you set an alert by sending email if the status is activate or deactivate. and suppose you have 4 pipelines, each pipeline will send 2 alerts mail, so you totally get 8 emails, right?

Comment: Do you want get all the pipeline status in one emails?

Comment: Yes Leon.. I want to send one status mail for all pipelines. Lets say I have 15 pipelines so in the mail I want to send 15 pipelines status- Succeeded/failed.                                       Is there any way if we can share dashboard workbook/query result in the mail ?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I misunderstood you. You set an alert by sending email if the status is activate or deactivate. and suppose you have 4 pipelines, each pipeline will send 2 alerts mail, so you totally get 8 emails.

If that's the case, you don't have an option to send a single status email having all pipelines status. The alert will periodically check the status for each pipeline, and if the condition is met, an alert will be sent. There's no way to configure this.

Comment: Yes, as per alert rule which I created I am getting 2 mails.. you understood it correct.  Is there any other way where we can get one mail only having status of all pipelines?

Comment: @Neha we cannot do that. It's based on your query which is used to set the alert.  If your query checked these status(like both activate / deactivate), then during alert scans, if any condition is met, it will send the related alert.

Comment: @Neha since it's by designed, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Comment: @ Ivan, I  am still waiting for the answer or other possible ways to achieve it.